# Adding an Option param if it exists to my map during initial creation

Tags: scala

Is it possible to add the param d if it exists to my Map during the initial creation of it or do I have to do a .copy after I create the val m?

```
def doAbc(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: Option[Int]): Unit = {
  val m = Map(
    "a" -> a,
    "b" -> b,
    "c" -> c
  )

  someService.doBLank(m)
}
```

Comment: You appear to be building a `Map[String,String]` but your `d` parameter is an `Option[Int]`. How would an `Int` fit in your `Map`?

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest approach is probably something like this

```
def doAbc(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: Option[Int]): Unit = {
  val m = Map(
    "a" -> a,
    "b" -> b,
    "c" -> c
  ) ++ d.map("d" -> _ )

  someService.doBLank(m)
}
```

ie. Since map has a function to add traversables of tuples to it. This doesn't technically create it during initial creation, though, but I think it fits the goal of your question.

Comment: it should read `("d" -> _)`  (somehow I can't make the edit). not sure if you even need the .toList